# Problema com configuração de customErrors ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso configurar um página de erro genérica para o meu site, adicionei o seguinte código no web config:

```
<system.web>
  <trust level="Full" />
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Error/index.cshtml">
    <error redirect="~/Views/Error/index.cshtml" statusCode="500" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Criei o Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SiteTeste.Controllers
{
    public class ErrorController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Criei a View:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="container-fluid">
<div style="margin-top:100px;margin-bottom:100px;" class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    <h1>Ocorreu um erro durante a requisição.</h1>
    Ocorreu um erro interno, por gentileza repita o processo ou @Html.ActionLink("Entre em contato","ContactUs","Home") caso o erro persista.
  </div>
</div>
```

Porém quando acontece um erro o que aparece para mim é a mensagem:

> Error.
>
> An error occurred while processing your request.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Em seu template padrão, o mvc vai redirecionar o erro para `~\Views\Shared\Error.cshml`. Você pode simplesmente substituir essa view pela sua e não precisará mais se preocupar com isso.

Se você olhar no método  `Application_Start()` verá que existe uma linha chamando

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

Que por sua vez registra o filter

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Se você quiser um tratamento diferenciado você pode implementar o seu próprio handler com os tratamentos e direcionamentos que achar pertinente.

Comment: Agora entendi de onde veio essa pagina, porém não resolveu o problema, como alterar essa página. :/

Comment: Você editou a `~\Views\Shared\Error.cshml` ou não conseguiu redirecionar para a sua?

Comment: Eu criei uma View Error